# SQL query for calculating percentage completion of a survey

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, logic

Here I have a survey and survey has many questions.Question has many answers.This is very basic relation of my survey.Every question is having a 'sequence number'.This 'sequence number' is used for defining 'next question sequnce number' in answers.So based on few answers the next question will get decided.For example,

```
---------------------- first page -----------------------
    1ques[page1])Are you married?(seq_num:1)
       Answer) a.Yes (next question sequnce number = 4)
               b.No  (next question sequnce number = 5)

    2ques[page1])Are you interested in colors ?(seq_num:2)
       Answer) a.Yes (next question sequnce number = 6)
               b.No  

    3ques[page1])Are you interested in colors ?(seq_num:3)
       Answer) a. < 25 years 
               b. >= 25 years  
=========================end===========================
```

If I answer like this,1ques[page1]=> **b.No** , 2ques[page1]=> **b.Yes** , 3ques[page1]=> **b. >= 25 years**  ,then

```
---------------------- second page -----------------------
1ques[page2])Is there any plan for your wedding in next one year?(seq_num:5)
   Answer) a.Yes (next question sequnce number = 2)
           b.No  (next question sequnce number = 3)

2ques[page2])Which type of color do you like?(seq_num:6)
   Answer) a.light
           b.dark 
=========================end===========================
```

If I answer like this,1ques[page1]=> **b.Yes** , 2ques[page1]=> **b.No** , 3ques[page1]=> **a. < 25 years**  ,then

```
---------------------- second page -----------------------
1ques[page2])How many children do you have?(seq_num:4)
   Answer) a.Yes (next question sequnce number = 2)
           b.No  (next question sequnce number = 3)

2ques[page2])What is your interensts?(seq_num:7)
   Answer) a.Arts
           b.science 
=========================end===========================
```

the survey question and answer structure will be like this for so many pages.If the survey has quit in the middle or survey submitted without answering.By calculating all the cases survey completion should be calculated.Clearly I mean,For calculating completion percentage I need total questions.So In any of case How many total question does user will get is needed.Or any other way to calculate to completion percentage.For a reference , Here I am providing DB structure of surveys.

[image: Surveys]

[image: Survey Questions]

[image: Survey Answers]

Thanks!

Comment: Is this mysql or postgresql database? Also, can you add sample input data and required result to your question?

Comment: Any thing mysql or postgresql..But I need the logic to get the total question in all cases.Assume the data mentioned above images as real data.

Comment: We need real samples, not images. Add `create table` statements and `insert` statements with sample data, add required output. It is common practice to create demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). You get no relevant answers because as I believe many consider your question both incomplete and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you want ?
I guess you want to calculate percentage for restricting the submission means like if completion percentage should be more than 50%, something like that or what ?

Because the structure you shown here is so simple, but i am not getting your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have to calculate the completion percentage of survey?If a survey has n questions,I can calculate completion percentage by answered_questions/n.But here the n(total questions) value is depended on answers.If I choose an answer which is not having a next question sequence number,then the total questions is less when compare to I choose an answer which is having a next question sequence number.In any case I have to find completion percentage of survey.

Comment: Ok, if you select answer in such a way(sequence number in answer table) that you can answer only for 5 questions, where as total question is 20. Then your completion percentage will be  25%.